# What's better: adding new primitives or extrude from existing?

Tags: extrude, optimization

This is a very general question. I wanted to know what the advantages and disadvantages of extruding from an existing primitive be over adding a new primitive. To give an example, I have started modeling a hammer. The head is cube primitive. Should I extrude the handle from that cube primitive or should I add a cylinder primitive?

Can a new primitive make it more difficult to put a texture on it? Can a new primitive increase the processing that goes into using the model? Can a new primitive cause problems when rigging?

Please keep in mind that I am asking in general, not only for that hammer example. I am looking for answers that I can apply to all future models I can possibly create.

Thank you!

Comment: They both have their pros and cons, I would suggest watching this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yxrke72isQ He is making Thor's hammer and he is VERY good at Blender. Your question is hard to answer because it all depends. How many objects will your scene have, How good at animation are you? How good at UV unwrapping are you? How powerful is your computer? all these things depend of what you should do with your model(scene). I would model it how a pro would model it, then you will get an idea for next time of what you can cut out and not worry about certain aspects in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but:

Using only one mesh (extruding from an existing mesh) is absolutely needed if you need deformations, because all geometry is linked, and also can keep vert/poly count lower... it is the better choice in most cases, in my humble opinion.

Using separate mesh (adding a new primitive) could allow to keep independent mesh parts separated, for some reason (e.g.: to split them later while modeling), but also allow you to treat them as a single object in animation (without deformation).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you prefer. My suggestion here is, try to make a hammer by extruding its parts if it is convenient for you but if you find it too difficult, then you can add a new mesh. However, at the end of your modelling and texturing, you will have to join the parts together so even if you have used a group of meshes, they will become one again at the end. In my experience, I found adding new meshes convenient but when you have to attach them to other parts, it may be really time consuming especially for irregularly shaped items. In the case of a hammer I would definitely extrude.